# How to write JUnit test case for void method

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am trying to write Junit test cases for a void method. This method is used for updating  values in Database. I have tried certain test cases and its returning a success. But when I check the coverage its showing zero. Can anyone tell me the proper way to write test cases for void methods.

this is my service class :

```
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {


  @Autowired
  ERepository eRepository;

  @Autowired
  ActivityUtil activityUtil;


  @Override
  public void updateCustomer(RequestDTO requestDTO)
      throws CustomAException {
    if (Objects.nonNull(requestDTO.getAdmissionId())) {
      Optional<Admission> optionalAdmission = eRepository.findById(
          requestDTO.getAdmissionId());
      if (optionalAdmission .isPresent()) {
        EAdmission eAdmission = optionalAdmission.get();
        updateCustomer(requestDTO, eAdmission);
      } else {
     
        throw new CustomAException ("Admission details not found");
      }
    }
    else {
      throw new CustomAException ("Admission id  not found");
    }
  }

  private void updateCustomer(RequestDTO requestDTO,
      EAdmission eAdmission)
      throws CustomAException {
    logger.info("updating customer info");
    try {
      if (ObjectUtils.isNotEmpty(eAdmission.getCustomer())) {
        eAdmission.getCustomer().setCustomerEmailAddress(
            requestDTO.getEmail());
        eAdmission.getCustomer().setCorporateTelephoneNumber(
            requestDTO.getCustomerPhone());
        eAdmission.getCustomer().setZipCode(requestDTO.getZipCode());
        eAdmission.getCustomer().setCustomerAddress1(requestDTO.getAddress1());
        evfAdmissionRepository.save(evfAdmission);
        activityUtil.createActivityLog(eAdmission, Constants.ENTRY_COMPLETED);
      } else {
        throw new CustomAException ("Customer details not found ");
      }
    } catch (Exception exception) {
      logger.error(Constants.CUSTOMER_UPDATE_ERROR_MESSAGE);
      throw new CustomAException (Constants.CUSTOMER_UPDATE_ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

I am trying to write test cases for updateCustomer but my test class has zero coverage even though its a success.

test class :

```
@SpringBootTest
public class CustomerServiceImplTest {

  @InjectMocks
  CustomerServiceImpl CustomerServiceImpl;

  @Mock
  ERepository eRepository ;

  @Mock
  ActivityUtil activityUtil;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }

  @Test
  public void updateCustomerException() throws Exception {
    CustomerServiceImpl CustomerServiceImplTest = mock(CustomerServiceImpl.class);
    when(evfAdmissionRepository.findById(any())).thenThrow(ConstraintViolationException.class);
    Mockito.doThrow(CustomAException .class).when(CustomerServiceImplTest).updateCustomer(setRequestDTO());
    }

  @Test
  public void updateCustomerSuccess() throws Exception {
    CustomerServiceImpl CustomerServiceImplTest = mock(CustomerServiceImpl.class);
 
    CustomerServiceImplTest .updateCustomer(setRequestDTO());
    //doNothing().when(evfCustomerServiceImpl).updateEVFCustomerOnSubscribe(any());
    verify(CustomerServiceImplTest ).updateCustomerOn(setRequestDTO());
  }

private RequestDTO setRequestDTO() {
    RequestDTO eRequestDTO = new RequestDTO ();
    eRequestDTO .setEmail("test");
  // rest of code for setting value
    return eRequestDTO ;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

ArgumentCaptor can be used to capture and Assert Arguments in your method. you can read about [ArgumentCaptor](https://site.mockito.org/javadoc/current/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html) here